Fullcalendar multi-month grid skip specific months when using duration to make course view
I'm trying to display a view as a school course, which spans through two years skipping july and august as these count as vacation.


options = <CalendarOptions>{
    plugins: [multiMonthPlugin],
    initialView: 'multiMonthYear',
    multiMonthMaxColumns: 6,
    multiMonthMinWidth: 100,
    headerToolbar: {
      center: 'dayGridMonth,customView' // buttons for switching between views
    },
    views: {
      customView: {
        type: 'multiMonthYear',
        duration: { months: 10 },
        buttonText: 'custom'
      }
    },
    initialDate: startOfYear(new Date()),
  }



I tried using duration, dateIncrement and visibleRange but i can't figure out a way to make it work, suggestions are welcome

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is not possible in fullCalendar currently, unfortunately. If you want to request a feature see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features
